# Webservice with IIS 7.5and asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, iis-7.5

I have a webservice in c# i wan't to host it with IIS7.5
All the security settings has been done, i think. But when i run one of the functions with SOAP UI, it doens't respond well. I get a good return in SOAP UI that means there is no failure in the webservice,
but i don't get the right result! The function does not execute..
Can someone help me?